# javascript doesn't work in Cordova project

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, phonegap-build

i have a web project which works find in web. I want to transfer it into phonegap windows phone project . 
Everything works fine but in a search option whenever i click in the search option it shows nothing showing a message "We are having trouble to display this message". N:B: this search option works properly in the web.
here is my search code:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/init.js"></script>
<script> 
    var c=getCatalogue();
    var bestNew=getBestNew();

    $("#recherche").click(function(){
        var v=$("#search").val();
        window.localStorage.setItem("search",v);
        if(v!="") routePage("recherche.html?search="+v);
    });     
</script>
```

I think problem is when i pass the value to another page that is "search="+v".
When i use `if(v!="") routePage("recherche.html);` instead of `if(v!="") routePage("recherche.html?search="+v);` then it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading and using JavaScript imports locally instead of fetching a remote version if not strictly necessary.

See: 
    `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>`

Also `phonegap.js` should be included:
    `<script type="text/javascript" src="phonegap.js"></script>`

Comment: I have tried this already but problem is the same. @t.spetebroot

Comment: @kkkk do you call `app.initialize()` in your initialisation script? (./init.js)

Comment: It works well in web version.  When i used local jquery-2.1.1.min.js it doesn't shows the error but nothing is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to move the JQuery source to a local file and update your script tag, like you have with materialize.min.js.  Loading library JS from the network is not a good idea as it slows your app's startup down and also will cause it to fail when started in a situation where there is no network access.

Additionally Cordova/PhoneGap's [Content Security Policy](http://content-security-policy.com/) may be blocking remote script loads for security reasons - you don't state which PhoneGap/Cordova version you are using, but this may be a problem for you in Cordova 5.  There's a tutorial on dealing with that [here](http://moduscreate.com/cordova-5-ios-9-security-policy-changes/).  You can configure around this by adjusting the Content Security Policy meta tag to allow script-src from other than "self" but I wouldn't recommend this.

When running in Cordova/PhoneGap you should also wait for the ["deviceready" event](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.1.1/cordova/events/events.deviceready.html) before trying to do anything, to make sure that the framework is fully initialized and that you have access to call plugins.

Also instead of loading new pages you should architect your app so that it is a single page app and generates page fragments from templates as needed.  Try looking at something like Handlebars for this unless you have another preferred solution.  I have a complete demo app that uses this approach that you can look at the source for [here](https://github.com/simonprickett/bartcordova).

Comment: I have used js/jquery-2.1.1.min.js this. In this case there is no error message but no search result is shown although it works fine in web version. Now what should i do?? @Simon Prickett